# What does the broom in the top right corner represent?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

In the Blackout mode of Call of Duty: Black Ops 4, there is a small broom that appears in the top right corner between the number of kills the player has gotten that round and the total number of players that remain in the match.

[image: Screenshot of broom]

**What does this broom counter keep track of?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how many downed enemies you've killed. The kill, however, goes to player, who shot the enemy down initially (you may get both if you done both).

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I played a few more games and it looks like this is correct.

Comment: I haven't played duos or quads by myself, but I've made such conclusion after watching several streams and how streamers were getting score.